# How to greyout NSMenuitem using setEnabled in objective-c

Tags: objective-c, xcode

This is what i have done If you have defined your `NSMenuItem` in your header and connected it through your XIB, you can simply call the Hidden property.

`[myMenuItem setHidden:YES];`
 "Greying out" the menuItem would be `[myMenuItem setEnabled: NO];`
 I am able to hide using [myMenuItem setHidden:YES]; but i am not able to grey out using

```
[myMenuItem setEnabled: NO];
```

Should i do further modifications in `XIB`

Comment: Is your `NSMenu` set to autoenable items? See https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSMenu_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000267-SW12